# Some character are not identified as character from string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading the text from the image using AWS Recognition. Able to get the text properly from the image but I am using a regular expression to check the format of the text eg: the first 5 characters should be alphabet and the next 4 digits only. But it is unable to identify characters as alphabets sometime. Below is the sample data

```
import re
str= "СТЕРК7383"
re.match("[A-Z]{5}\d{4}",str)
```

It will return no match found.

If i am trying to lower on this string. It is returning something else.

```
str= "СТЕРК7383"
str.lower()
  'стерк7383'
```

Let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: It's Cyrillic, not Latin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your character are not ascii ones (you can see it when you lower the string).

Using the `\w` instead of `[A-Z]` works better. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched.

```py
import re

one_str = "СТЕРК7383"
res = re.match(r"\w{5}\d{4}", one_str)
print(res)
```

Also, `str` is a built-in work, you should not use it.

Comment: Thank you. \w solves my major problem but i have to identify only alphabets with upper case from the string.

Answer (score 1):

`A-Z` will of course only match uppercase letters from the Latin alphabet. Since your string contains Cyrillic characters, it won't match anything.

To match any Unicode word character, use `\w` instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"\w{5}\d{4}", "СТЕРК7383")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='СТЕРК7383'>
```

Comment: Thank you @Thomas.  \w solves my major problem but i have to identify only alphabets with upper case from the string. How to achieve that using \w.

Comment: There is nothing in `re` that helps you there, but you can call `upper()` on the string and check if it's equal to the original.